# Await task until task result == foo

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, events, async-await

I'm not sure how to code this logic. I want to be able to listen for new messages outside of the code scope that receives the websocket messages. I have to be able to ultimately make an async function called `WaitForMessage(string msg)`, so this can't really be achieved with events as far as I know. I use .NET Core. I thought the logic should look kind of like this:

```
var messages = new();
foo();
bar();

async task foo(){
    while(messages.message != "foobar")
        await messages.WaitForNewMessage();
}

async Task bar(){
    Task.delay(5000);
    messages.NewMessage("foobar");
}
```

Any alternative methods or ways of achieving my goal is much appreciated.

I tried using events, but I can't wait for an event to be raised, I can only subscribe a function to the event, so that doesn't seem like good practice / even possible.

Comment: If this is for .NET Core, you might look at the `BufferBlock<T>` class.

Comment: To await anything, use `TaskCompletionSource<T>`.

Comment: @rfmodulator works great for single use, but I want to be able to wait for several messages at the same time. I could create a BufferBlock for each listener, but that seems like it would be bad practice.

Comment: How are you receiving the message from the websocket?

Comment: @JohanP async through a buffer/streamreader.

Comment: @MrDoe so if your streamreader is already exposing async waiting/receiving of messages, why do you need to reimplement that?

Comment: @JohanP perhaps I formulated myself wrong, but what I need is to be able to await specific messages in functions other than the one that receives the messages. Basically like awaiting the BufferBlock mentioned above, but preferably multiple listeners should be possible. I can easily receive messages async, but lets say i want to wait for a pong message from a server in a heartbeat function, id like to be able to say "await messages.WaitForMessage('pong');". Sorry for the long comment.

Comment: Maybe you can consider repurposing the conditional middleware pattern https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/conditional-middleware-based-on-request-in-asp.net-core

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, this code will be sufficient. I have not tested it as I don't know how your websocket message receiving code looks like.

```cs
public async Task WaitForMessage(string message)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var read = await _reader.ReadToEndAsync(); //whatver your code is for async receiving a chunk of text

        if (read == message)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

and then the calling code

```cs
async Task Foo()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await messages.WaitForMessage("foobar");
    }
}
```